# Passing HTML values using GET request

Tags: node.js, get, request, query-string

I am trying to pass a HTML form elements value into node.js file via GET request.

How do I do it?

I have found similar examples with POST requests but I need to use GET request alone here.
The HTML form value is the search string I am going to use to search in database.

```js
app.get('/search', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile('./views/search.html');
    console.log(req.body.denomination);
    user.find({denomination: req.params.denomination}, function (err, docs) { 
        res.render('index', {users: docs});
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <label for="denomination">Denomination</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="denomination"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="like(this)">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get values after a GET request you can use `req.query.<your_html_field>`.

Also, check if you have set `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` to allow you search the `querystring`. You can find more information [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended).

I'm not sure about your `res.sendfile(...)` in the beginning of your method, whether it's sending a response already or not, but I assume it's working.

Just make these two little changes in your route:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile('./views/search.html');

    // Changed here from `body` to `query`
    console.log(req.query.denomination);

    // Changed here from `params` to `query`
    user.find({denomination: req.query.denomination}, function (err, docs){
        res.render('index', {users: docs});
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.